# How to get application DEBUG and INFO messages properly logged in Play 2.4?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.4

From [Play 2.4 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsLogger), the default application logging level should be DEBUG, right:

```
<logger name="play" level="INFO" />
<logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />
```

However, in my logs I only get WARN and ERROR level messages.

For example this code:

```
class Application extends Controller {

  val log = Logger(this.getClass)

  def index = Action {
    log.debug("debug")
    log.info("info")
    log.warn("warn!")
    log.error("ERROR")
    Ok("ok")
  }    
}
```

...only yields this in stdout (ditto in `logs/application.log`):

```
[warn] c.Application - warn!
[error] c.Application - ERROR
```

How to get application DEBUG and INFO messages properly logged?

Using Play 2.4.3, with basically default configs, and no `conf/logback.xml` at all. (SBT-based project setup, no Typesafe Activator.)

---

To clarify, I know I can create a custom config file (`conf/logback.xml`) for Logback. That is obvious from the documentation I linked to in the very first sentence.

The **point** here was: if my needs are extremely ordinary (get my app's messages logged, also debug and info), do I really need to create a lengthy custom configuration file? One would assume a thing as basic as this would work by default, or with some minimal config option. If you’ve paid attention, Play Framework is touted as one with [good *developer experience*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0gRE.jpg), and many things with it follow the “convention over configuration” principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I learned from a [colleague](https://github.com/malliina) in our backend chat:

> Your Application controller probably resides in the controllers
>   package, right? When you do `Logger(getClass)` <- getClass is used to
>   look up the package path to Application, which then would be
>   `controllers.Application` so you can for example add a line `<logger
>   name="controllers" level="DEBUG" />` to get debug output from classes
>   in the controllers package

There *is* one way without custom configs (which worked for INFO but not DEBUG with a quick experiment). But it has **significant drawbacks** compared to using more granual loggers (as in my question).

> The "application" logger is the default logger name that's used if you
>   use the Logger object directly, like `Logger.info("Hello, world!")`, as
>   opposed to creating your own instances
>
> [...]
>
> But that will clearly backfire quickly since then you lose granular
>   configuration of your logs and can only filter the logging "globally",
>   so I never use that.
>   Also, your logs will not disclose where the log statement is
>   made but instead just print that it's in "application"

I don't want those drawbacks, so I did create `conf/logback.xml` (starting with a copy of the [default](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsLogger)) and added custom loggers along the lines of:

```
<logger name="controllers" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="services" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="repositories" level="DEBUG" />
```

So now my `val log = Logger(this.getClass)` approach works.

But I fail to see how requiring 30-40 lines of custom XML for pretty much the most basic thing imaginable is good [developer experience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0gRE.jpg). If some Play advocate or developer could justify why this doesn't work out of the box with default config, I'd be interested in hearing that.

Comment: this is insanity

Answer (score 0):

You have no .xml file at all inside the conf folder?
Adding this line should fix it for you:

```
<logger name="controllers" level="DEBUG" />
```

You can also override it on the application.conf file, although it will be deprecated in the future:

```
logger.controllers=DEBUG
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to get logging working *without* custom config. What I want is so *very* basic that it strikes me as odd if Play requires a lenghty piece of custom XML to make it work.